# Using regex to see if a UNIX process is up

Tags: perl, ps

In UNIX, I am checking to see if a process is up by executing the following command;

E.g.

```
psg dtllst pe99
```

This returns the following output if the process is running;

```
UID    PID    PPID    C    STIME    TTY    TIME CMD
pe99   1234   1       0 03:29:44    pts/8  0:01 dtllst pe99
```

Now in Perl, I want to be able to find out whether this process is up or not. So far I am doing the following

```
`my $checkProc = `psg dttlst | grep $myNode 2>&1`;`    #where $myNode is something like pe01 or pe02 or pe65 or pe99 etc...
```

Now after this I do the following to see if the above Perl command has returned what I am looking for to see if the process is up;

```
if ($checkProc =~ m/dtllst $myNode | $myNode/) {
    #yes, process is up
} else {
    #no, process is down
}
```

However this is not working - specifically, regardless of whether the UNIX process is alive or not, my code ALWAYS evaluates the if statement as true. I know this is wrong. 
I have tried to escape the "$" character in the regex to see if this was the issue and I have also tried removing the Perl variables from within the regex altogether.

What am I missing here? I know my regex is wrong somewhere :(

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The command `pgrep` prints the list of PIDs for all processes (other than itself) that match a `grep`-compatible regular expression.

It prints nothing if there are no matches.

This should be a sufficient test: `[ $(pgrep process | wc) -gt 0 ]` is true if the process is running. False if not.

Comment: In some cases, it is useful to use flag -f with the `pgrep`. It enables searching for full command line name. For instance, if a program is started with `java -jar bla.jar`, `pgrep bla` would fail, while `pgrep -f bla` would succeed.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why you are using `[`. Just use `pgrep process > /dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `psg`, but I know (the hard way, so to speak) if I run `ps ax | grep progname` to see if any process is running that contains `progname`, I'll always get a yes, since `grep progname` is itself a command that contains "progname".

I don't know perl, but in bash, I get around this like this, e.g., if I want to check if any instance of progname is running, I run `ps ax | grep -c "[p]rogname"`, which solves the problem of always getting a yes.

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp `m/dtllst $myNode | $myNode/` will match (in particular) any occurrence of `$myNode`.  By construction, `psg dtllst | grep $myNode` will return something that matches `$myNode`, so you regexp always matches.

If you cannot follow other people's advice and use `pgrep` or `ps ... | grep` or variants thereof, you could either:

1. set "$checkProc = `psg dtllst | grep 'dtllst $myNode'`;" and then just test if `$checkProc` is non-empty, or
2. set "$checkProc = `psg dtllst`;" and then match it against `m/dtllst $myNode/`
3. Use the [Proc::ProcessTable](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Proc-ProcessTable/ProcessTable.pm) CPAN module and just search for an entry `$p` such that `$p->cmdline =~ m/dtllst $myNode/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you're looking for, but this is how you can get the PID of your program:

```
ps -e -o pid= -o args= | sed 's/^\s*//' | grep 'dtllst pe99' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

This will output all, if any PIDs for the given command with arguments.

You can use that to pipe it into another program, if you like, and if you need all of the PIDs at once, you can wrap the whole thing in `$()`:

```
MyPIDs=$(ps -e -o pid= -o args= | sed 's/^\s*//' | grep 'dtllst pe99' | cut -d' ' -f1)
echo $MyPIDs
```